# How can I get or/and from two expressions in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   table A
WHERE  CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) IN
       (CONVERT(DATE, time_created), CONVERT(DATE, time_updated))
```

I tried `or` after the , but it didn't work out.

Comment: what mean "didnt work out"  .. you have error  .. ??

Comment: Please edit your question with the sample data as DDL+DML and desired results. Also, it's always good to tag the relevant product (I beleive sql server in your case) and the version you are working with.

Comment: Not sure about your question... But if you are using getdate() along with date conversion you can put that into variable and use it

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `getdate()` and `convert()` are non-standard functions

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server?  If so, is this what you intend?

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM table A
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, time_created) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) OR
      CONVERT(DATE, time_updated) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

If so, then your original query should also work.